# Flask route using path with trailing slash

Tags: python, flask, routes

I have a route of the type:

```
@app.route("/api/repositories/<path:repo>")
```

Where the `repo` parameter can contain a trailing slash, like `foo-tests/`

However Flask removes it from the path converting `foo-tests/` into `foo-tests` in my view function.

Is there a way force Flask to not remove the trailing slash from the path?

Comment: do you really need this `/`? Can't you add it later in code?

Comment: It doesn't depend on me but on the URL's `repo` value given to me, which can or cannot have `/`.

Comment: are you sure it is important to have this `/` ? Maybe your code should add `/` to all URLs?

Comment: I tested `path` and it gives me with `/` at the end when I send `foo-tests/`. Maybe some other element changes it - ie. web server (apache, nginx, gunicorn) or some proxy.

Comment: Oh, that's very possible.